# Out Animation in textillate.js is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

My code is as follows:

```
<div class="header">
<h1>My text</h1>
</div>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('h1').textillate({in:{} , out:{effect:'hinge'}});
});
</script>
```

In this, the `in-animation` works well but the `out-animation` doesn't work. You can refer to the [textillate.js jquery plugin docs](http://jschr.github.io/textillate/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The out effects are only run as a way to transition to the next in effect unfortunately. Try using empty text as the next transition:

```
// html
<h1 class="tlt">
    <ul class="texts">
         <li>Some Title</li>   
         <li> </li>
    </ul>
</h1>

// javascript
$('.tlt').textillate();
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jschr/y9m3b/

https://github.com/jschr/textillate/issues/5

Answer (score 2):

Adding textilate('out') to the callback function for the 'in' effect worked for me.

This code executes the 'fadeOut' effect after the 'fadeIn' effect.

```
$('.myclass').textillate({
    loop: false,
    in : {
        effect: 'fadeIn',
        callback: function() {
            $('.myclass').textillate('out');
        }
    },
    out: {
        effect: 'fadeOut',
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Great plugin! Without using `loop: true` option I can't let work the out effect:

```
$(function () {
    $('h1').textillate({ in : {
            effect: 'fadeInLeftBig'
        },
        out: {
            effect: 'hinge'
        },
        loop: true
    });
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/zHKLC/2/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can you find any solution for the out animation to work without looping????

Answer (score 0):

It is a flaw that should be fixed, but callback allows anything to be possible, so I've used that to do some pretty cool things. I solved this problem like this.

```
    $('.intro_1').textillate({
    loop: true,
    in:{ 
        effect: 'rollIn' 
    },
    out: { 
        effect: 'rollOut',
        callback: function () 
        {
            $('.intro_1').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  $element.textillate('out') on the callback function of the in parameter, it works